# Cannot align rows with chain restraints

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a widget that, no matter what constraints I place upon it and other widgets, including the addition of barriers, always positions itself at the top of the layout.

This is a fairly simple arrangement of two rows of two elements each, not aligned column wise.  The first element in each row is a TextView label, the second an input (Spinner).
There is also a lone TextView title above the first row stretching all the way across. By my understanding and previous experience with constraint layout, this shouldn't require a barrier between the rows, and that was my initial version.

This is the design view, where the selected element ("Credentials") is supposed to be in the second row but instead appears *above* the first row, over top of the title TextView ("PKIX"):

[image]

Actual result in the emulator looks much the same. The selected "Credentials" element is the fourth of five elements in the XML layout below.  All of the other elements are in the right place.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_pkix_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottomborder"
        android:text="PKIX"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/addsrv_trust_lbl"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_trust_lbl"
        android:text="Trust"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addsrv_pkix_title"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/addsrv_cred_lbl"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/addsrv_trust_lbl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addsrv_pkix_title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/addsrv_cred_spin"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_cred_lbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10sp"
        android:text="Credentials"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/addsrv_cred_spin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addsrv_trust_lbl"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/addsrv_cred_spin"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_cred_spin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/addsrv_cred_lbl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm perplexed.  The `addsrv_cred_lbl` TextView ("Credentials") is:

- Start aligned with parent.
- End aligned with the `addsrv_cred_spin` spinner, which appears correctly positioned;
  this alignment is reciprocated to create a horizontal chain. They are also baseline
  aligned.
- Top aligned with the bottom of the TextView above it, `addsrv_trust_lbl`.
  This alignment is also reciprocated.

There's no bottom alignment yet (there's another row to go); bottom aligning it with the parent makes no difference unless I bottom align the spinner from the same row, in which case the result goes from bad to worse.

Since this did not work, I tried to use a barrier between the rows.  If I use it as a "top", with the second row widgets as the constraint referents, the barrier appears at the top, above the title, regardless of what constraints are used to position it below the first row. Used as a "bottom", with the first row widgets referenced and the second row chained below it (which is more logical), things are a little bit better in that the barrier appears in the right place -- but the "Credentials" widget is still up top.

The design view of this looks exactly the same as the previous one except the barrier is visible below the first row.  In the XML, I aslo added `optimizationLevel="none"` after having read this can help with misbehaving barriers (but it made no difference).  There's also a few stylistic elements added back here (such as font size) I removed for brevity before.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_optimizationLevel="none"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_pkix_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottomborder"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/tbar"
        android:text="PKIX"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/addsrv_bigfont"
        android:textColor="@color/titleText"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/addsrv_trust_lbl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_trust_lbl"
        android:text="Trust"
        android:textSize="@dimen/addsrv_fontsz"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addsrv_pkix_title"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/addsrv_bar1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/addsrv_trust_lbl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addsrv_pkix_title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/addsrv_bar1"
        />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_bar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="addsrv_trust_lbl,addsrv_trust_spin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/addsrv_cred_lbl"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_cred_lbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:paddingHorizontal="10sp"
        android:text="Credentials"
        android:textSize="@dimen/addsrv_fontsz"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/addsrv_cred_spin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/addsrv_cred_spin"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addsrv_bar1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_cred_spin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/addsrv_cred_lbl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addsrv_bar1"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Am I correct in observing that some of the constraints on `addsrv_cred_lbl` are being completely ignored?**  Doesn't `topToBottom` mean that the top of the widget is aligned with the bottom of the other?  Instead, it seems simply to mean that they will be connected with a squiggly, potentially curved and convoluted line in the design view, and the spacial relation of the two widgets is arbitrary, such that the semantic logic might as well be inverted, "top = bottom, bottom = top", etc.

Please note that **I do not want to use absolute values to position anything**.  If the only way to get this to work is to do that, constraint layout seems a complete waste of time even in this simple case, and I'd rather just stack some liner layouts.

Comment: I've removed the baseline constraints and it looks right. Are you sure that Spinner has `baseline` at all?

Comment: It seems the problem is that you're trying to tie the lavbel of the second row to the baseline of the Spinner. I am not sure Spinner even has something like that. I tried the first example and just tie it to the bottom instead of baseline and it seemed to position correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that works (I also had to remove a 24sp top margin that was snuck into the "Credentials" widget by the design view at some point, removed it here too).  Dunno why I would be allowed to create a baseline constraint if it actually can't be useful (and why wouldn't a spinner displaying text have a baseline?). Also,  would be great if even *one* of the stack of borderline spurious warnings ("Hardcoded Text", "Insufficient color contrast" ...) referred to this.  Don't need the barrier now either. Grrrr.  Anway: Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Spinner` doesn't have a baseline. You were trying to tie it to the baseline of the item inside the `Spinner` is my guess - `ConstraintLayout` can't reach children of its children.

You can check it via the design tab with a right click. `TextView`s will show an option "Show baseline" but the `Spinner` doesn't.

[image: Text view has a baseline]
[image: Spinner doesnt]

Also snippet from the doc

> Align the text baseline of a view to the text baseline of another
> view.

That's what baselines are for, if you want two `TextView`s connect together so they don't have the height where the text starts messed up.

I think there is a tiny flaw in your approach to the chain. You were setting the top constraint of both elements in each row to the bottom of the previous row(or title in the first row).  Even if the `Spinner` would have a baseline, this would make the label off-centered in relation to the `Spinner`(slightly higher because the baseline of a text is higher than the actual bottom of the view).

I think the best approach in these types of layouts is to have one guiding element(which is also the element of the chain) that represents the row and let other elements be positioned in relation to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_pkix_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="PKIX"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_trust_lbl"
        android:text="Trust"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/addsrv_trust_lbl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addsrv_pkix_title"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/addsrv_cred_spin"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_cred_lbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10sp"
        android:text="Credentials"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/addsrv_cred_spin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/addsrv_cred_spin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/addsrv_cred_spin"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_cred_spin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/addsrv_cred_lbl"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

NOTE: I added the last bottom constraint to the parent and "`spread`" to the chain for demonstration but also know that if you don't have the bottom of the last view constrained to something - it's not a chain.

Answer (score 2):

Working with `ConstraintLayout` is easy if you obey few simple rules:

1. Create one chain. That means Views hooking to each other reciprocally, all the way.
2. Now that you have a working chain, you can manipulate it with            `layout_constraintVertical_bias` and `layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle`. If changing those does nothing, it means your chain is broken.
3. hook remaining Views to ones laid out by the chain
4. every control must have 4 constraints: top, bottom, start and end
5. do not create competing chains and try to force them into working together.

`Spinner` cannot have baseline, only `TextView` and its descendants have it. `Spinner` is `AdapterView`, so it can contain whatever you can imagine.

BTW: don't use @+id to refer to existing ids. Plus means creating new id, so if you make a typo it will create new id that refers to nothing instead of error "there's no such id".

Here's an example: top label and Spinners form the main chain and side labels are positioned each to their Spinner:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_pkix_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10sp"
        android:background=""
        android:text="PKIX"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_trust_lbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10sp"
        android:text="Trust"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/addsrv_cred_spin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/addsrv_trust_lbl"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/addsrv_pkix_title"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_cred_lbl"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10sp"
        android:text="Credentials"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/addsrv_cred_spin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/addsrv_cred_spin"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/addsrv_cred_spin"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/addsrv_cred_spin"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/addsrv_cred_lbl"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/addsrv_trust_spin"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```